# How to deal with scope in an ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, scope

I have defined variable `fc` before a `getJSON()` ajax request.

In the request, a new `feature` is pushed to `fc.features` for every linestring in the geojson file.  This works beautifully. What matters though is at the end: `fc` is only complete after every feature has been iterated through (in this case there are 5 features).  What I see in the console is every iteration of `fc` after a new feature is added (it grows with each iteration and the fifth iteration produces the final json that is needed). However, I cannot access `fc` outside of any of the functions as it turns up empty.

My goal is to write `fc` to a json.file but I am unable to as I do not know how get around the issue of lexical scoping.  Should I use a global variable or `var _this = this;` ?  How would one access `fc` after the five iterations?

```
var fc = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": []
}

$.getJSON("testROUTES.geojson", function (dat) {

    $.each(dat.features, function (key, val) {

//reverse coordinates

      val.geometry.coordinates = val.geometry.coordinates.map((coords) => {
    return [coords[1], coords[0]]
});

      line = val.geometry.coordinates;


var control = L.Routing.control({
  router: L.Routing.osrmv1({
        serviceUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/route/v1',
        profile: 'driving'
    }),
    waypoints: line,
    waypointMode: 'connect'
}).addTo(mymap);

control.on('routeselected', function(e) {

  var lineCoordinates = [],
    i,
    latLng;

  for (i = 0; i < e.route.coordinates.length; i++) {
    latLng = L.latLng(e.route.coordinates[i]);
    lineCoordinates.push([latLng.lng, latLng.lat]);
  }
          var json = {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry":
        {
          type: 'LineString',
          coordinates: lineCoordinates
        }
      };
          //console.log(json)
          fc.features.push(json)
          console.log(JSON.stringify(fc))

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call - also look into promises

Comment: Are you sure that's your full code?  It should work.  Only reason it wouldn't is if you are declaring fc as a variable inside a function. Try qualifying fc with window.fc

Comment: that's the full code - `fc.features` after the getJSON() request is empty and is also empty outside of the last function.  I am not using a framework

Comment: Looks like your doing `fc.features.push(json);` inside `control.on('routeselected', `... so it makes sense it'd wait until 'routeselected' before adding `json` to `features`.

Comment: Is `console.log(JSON.stringify(fc))` spitting out the expected result of 5 features?

Comment: Yes - first it logs the first feature, then the first + second feature, then the first + second + third feature... and so on until all features are in `fc`.   Console.log runs five times, once for every added feature

Comment: My guess is `fc` turns up empty (as you put it in your question) because your checking it's value before the `control.on` handler function runs. Maybe try adding a button that when clicked prints `fc` to console and click that button after `fc` has the 5 features. I'll bet you `fc` will show up as having the 5 features when you click the test button.

Comment: Something like `$(".myTestButton").click(function() {console.log("fc: ", fc)});`

Comment: I added this at the end - but `fc.features` is empty: 
`var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(fc));
$('<a href="data:' + data + '" download="data.json">download JSON</a>').appendTo('#container');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149767/discussion-between-rocky-sims-and-the-darkside).